# Use permalink in PHP with HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, permalinks

I have a question using HTML and PHP combined.

I have this little code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'program', 'posts_per_page' => 100 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<div class="singleprogram">';
            echo '<div class="entry-title"><a href="'the_permalink()'">';
            the_title();
            echo '</a></div>'; 
            echo '<div class="entry-content">';
            the_content();
            echo '</div></div>';

        endwhile;
```

If I use this, my page gets all blank. Any ID what I'm doing wrong??

( if i delete `the_permalink()` and leave a `href=""` blank then its working but of course it doesn't link to something )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the information. I found my own solution, don't know why this does work but it works.

```
echo '<div class="entry-title"><a href="';
        echo the_permalink();
        echo '">';
        echo $post->post_title;
        echo '</a></div>';
```

I had to break up the a href.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly concatenate the `the_permalink()` into the string. You can do this using the `.` operator.

Try this:

```
echo '<div class="entry-title"><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">';
```

You can also use the `,` operator for concatenation inside an `echo`:

```
echo '<div class="entry-title"><a href="' , the_permalink() , '">';
```

which, according to [**this source**](http://www.fusionswift.com/2010/05/php-concatenation-benchmark-comma-vs-period/), is slightly faster.

---

Without this, your page "gets all blank" because you have an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'the_permalink' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in ...
```

Which causes your program to crash.

To avoid the "white screen of death", [**enable error reporting**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) while developing. This will make debugging problems like this much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
When i use the dots in the script, i get the following result:
[link]http://www.octest.nl/testerror/error1.png
So the permalink is visible but needs to be placed in the a href

Comment: @user2190380 I think that is a different problem. The `.` works fine for the problem as shown. [**See this simple example**](http://codepad.org/qXTN065X)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you forgot the points for string-concatenation (e.g. ' . the_permalink() . ' ... not ' the_permalink ').

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
When i use the dots in the script, i get the following result:
[link]http://www.octest.nl/testerror/error1.png
So the permalink is visible but needs to be placed in the a href

Comment: Examine the element, using your browser's tools (in case of firefox: right-click and select "inspect element"). Or look at the source-code of the page. Maybe the "the_permalink()"-function creates a complete a-tag, in which case, you might have 2 a-tags inside of each other. - just a guess.